# Trying to understand python's struct.unpack command

Tags: c#, python

I have the following code which i have to translate to c#

```
pagefiles.sort()
for p in pagefiles:
try:
  contents = file(p).read()
except IOError:
  sys.stderr.write("error reading page file %s\n"% p)
  continue
(width, height,xres,yres) = struct.unpack('>IIII', contents[11:27])
```

I have some data recorded in one file for example, then read it and save it into contents variable, then from it using the last row command width, height, xres and yres are extracted, but seems i do not understand python good enough.
How to translate the last row from the code above?

```
        byte[] contents;
        List<byte[]> pagefiles = new List<byte[]>();
        foreach (byte[] array in pagefiles)
        {
            contents = array;
          // i should translate the last row here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been long time since I written any C#, but this is the essence of what needs to be done:

```
uint width  = (array[11] << 24) | (array[12] << 16) | (array[13] << 8) | array[14]
uint height = (array[15] << 24) | (array[16] << 16) | (array[17] << 8) | array[18]
uint xres   = (array[19] << 24) | (array[20] << 16) | (array[21] << 8) | array[22]
uint yres   = (array[23] << 24) | (array[24] << 16) | (array[25] << 8) | array[26]
```